# How to Get Image URI from Image selected From gallery. Android 5.0.2?

Tags: java, android

I aam new to android. Kindly provide me some help. I need the Image URI, before this i tried data.getData();  and pass it to  getContentResolver().query() but data.getData();  always returned null 
 Error is at thes lines:

Uri SelectedImageURI = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), SelectedImage);
   return Uri.parse(path);

My android version is 5.0.2

```
05-10 01:55:10.712 24424-24424/com.donateblood.blooddonation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.donateblood.blooddonation, PID: 24424
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.htc.HTCAlbum.action.ITEM_PICKER_FROM_COLLECTIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.donateblood.blooddonation/com.donateblood.blooddonation.UploadImage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3881)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1408)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
        at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:473)
        at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:463)
        at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:435)
        at com.donateblood.blooddonation.UploadImage.getImageUri(UploadImage.java:156)
        at com.donateblood.blooddonation.UploadImage.onActivityResult(UploadImage.java:102)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3877)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3931) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1408) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

---

```
package com.donateblood.blooddonation;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFS;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSInputFile;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;

/**
 * Created by YouCaf Iqbal on 4/26/2016.
 */
public class UploadImage extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int RESULT_LOAD = 1;
    @InjectView(R.id.imageView) ImageView ImageUpload;
    @InjectView(R.id.upload) Button Btn_Upload;
    @InjectView(R.id.proceed) Button Btn_Proceed;
    public String bloodgroup,name,password,number,email,picturePath,encodedPhotoString;
    Database dbobj = new Database();
    GPSTracker gps; private DB db;
    public double latitude=0;
    public double longitude=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.uploadimage);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        getCurrentLatLong();
        Btn_Upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                Intent upload = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                //Adding Croping
                upload.putExtra("crop","true");
                upload.putExtra("aspectX",1);
                upload.putExtra("aspectY",1);
                upload.putExtra("outputX",300);
                upload.putExtra("outputY",300);
                upload.putExtra("return-data",true);
                startActivityForResult(upload,RESULT_LOAD);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException E) {

                    String errorMessage = "Your device doesn't support the crop action!";
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
        Btn_Proceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Prcoess();
            }
        });
    }
    // When image is selected from Gallery
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==RESULT_LOAD && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            //Uri SelectedImageURI = (Uri)extras.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            Bitmap SelectedImage = extras.getParcelable("data");
            //Make Image rounded
            //Bitmap RoundedImage = getRoundedShape(SelectedImage);
           // Uri SelectedImageURI = data.getData();
            Uri SelectedImageURI = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), SelectedImage);

            picturePath = getRealPathFromURI(SelectedImageURI);
            ImageUpload.setImageBitmap(SelectedImage);
            // retrieve image path
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            try {
               // Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(SelectedImageURI, projection, null, null, null);
               //cursor.moveToFirst();
               // int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                // picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
               // cursor.close();
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                String fileNameSegments[] = picturePath.split("/");
                String fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];
                try {
                    File f = new File(picturePath);
                    Bitmap myImg = decodeFile(f,720);
                    //myImg = getResizedBitmap(myImg,100); // Compress it
                    // Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
                    // myImg = getResizedBitmap(myImg, 720);
                    myImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
                    byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
                    // Encode Image to String
                    encodedPhotoString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
                   // ImageUpload.setImageBitmap(myImg);

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this,"Unable to Set Image Try Again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                //Log.d("Picture Path", picturePath);
               // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+picturePath+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
               // Log.e("Path Error", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error finding path", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //
        }
    }
    public void Prcoess(){
        dbAsync signupThread = new dbAsync();
         signupThread.execute();
    }

    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }

    public class dbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UploadImage.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Account...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            GetUserDetails();
            dbobj.insertUser(name,email,password,number,bloodgroup,latitude,longitude,encodedPhotoString);
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+encodedPhotoString+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            onSignupSuccess();
        }
    }

    public void onSignupSuccess() {
       // btn_signup.setEnabled(true);
        //setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void GetUserDetails(){
        //mySpinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        bloodgroup = SignupActivity.bloodgroup.toString();
        name = SignupActivity.name.toString();
        email = SignupActivity.email.toString();
        password = SignupActivity.password.toString();
        number = SignupActivity.number.toString();
    }

    public void getCurrentLatLong(){
        gps = new GPSTracker(UploadImage.this);
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        }
    }

   public Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE){
       Bitmap b = null;

       //Decode image size
       BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

       FileInputStream fis = null;
       try {
           fis = new FileInputStream(f);
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
       try {
           fis.close();
           int scale = 1;
           if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
               scale = (int) Math.pow(2, (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE /
                       (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
           }
           //Decode with inSampleSize
           BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
           o2.inSampleSize = scale;
           fis = new FileInputStream(f);
           b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
           fis.close();

       }catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return b;
   }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ACTION_PICK` returns its result in the `Uri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK) in the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`. You call `getData()` to get this `Uri`. That's it. Hence, pretty much everything in your `if(requestCode==RESULT_LOAD && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)` block is not only wrong, but it is useless.

Beyond that, get rid of all the undocumented extras that you are placing on that `ACTION_PICK` `Intent`. Use [an image cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).

Comment: I tried 
// Uri SelectedImageURI = data.getData();
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(SelectedImageURI, projection, null, null, null);
               //cursor.moveToFirst();
               // int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                // picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
               // cursor.close();
But data.getData(); return null and gives on null object reference Null pointer exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117120/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-java-lang-stri
please check this out. I posted it there as well. but did not get response. I am newbie here. never mind 
Help me please

Comment: @YousafIqbal: There is not much that I can tell you. Unless whatever you used to pick from is very buggy, `getData()` will return the `Uri` of what the user picked. You do not use `query()` (as it is not needed) or `getRealPathFromURI()` (as it does not work). You [use a `ContentResolver` and methods like `openInputStream()` to work with the `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html), or hand it off to [an image-loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46).